# how to make single string of all key and values of map using lambda expression or stream

Tags: string, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

Map attributeMap = new TreeMap<>();

```
    attributeMap.put("C","FIRSTNAMe");
    attributeMap.put("C2","LASTNAMe");
    attributeMap.put("C3","1111");
    attributeMap.put("C4","ABCNAMe");
```

How to make single String of above example

output is c,c2,c3,c4 and FIRSTNAMe,LASTNAMe,'1111',ABCNAMe

Comment: I am also voting to close, you have shown zero effort here, SO is not about this

Comment: I have tried but getting error all time

Comment: If you have tried, then [edit] the question and add the code you tried and the error you're getting. Take some time to read the [help/on-topic] and [ask], and how to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    Predicate<String> predicate = "1111"::equals;
    String left = attributeMap.keySet().stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    String right = attributeMap.values().stream().map(x -> (predicate.test(x) ? "'" + x + "'" : x)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    System.out.println(left + right);
```

Comment: It possible to use entryset

Comment: @valamanoj yeah you could use just `entrySet` and do some nasty reducing for example, but I don't see the benefit

Comment: `String.join(",",attributeMap.keySet()).toLowerCase() + " and " + String.join(",",attributeMap.values()).replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\b", "'$0'")`

Comment: Yes but i want to make changes into values like as add single quotes